# JMS performance

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, message-queue

I'm having a bit of trouble with understanding JMS from a performance perspective. We have this very straightforward code in our application:

```
QueueConnection connection = null;
QueueSession session = null;
QueueSender sender = null;
TextMessage msg = null;

try {
  // The JNDIHelper uses InitialContext to look up things
  QueueConnectionFactory qcf = JNDIHelper.lookupFactory();
  Queue destQueue = JNDIHelper.lookupQueue();

  // These objects are created for every message, which is quite slow
  connection = qcf.createQueueConnection();
  session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  sender = session.createSender(destQueue);

  // This is the actual message
  msg = session.createTextMessage(xmlMsg);
  sender.setTimeToLive(0);
  sender.send(msg);
} 
finally {

  // Close all objects again
  JMSUtilities.safeClose(sender);
  JMSUtilities.safeClose(session);
  JMSUtilities.safeClose(connection);
}
```

The code is correct, but probably some of the above artefacts could be reused for several messages. These are our configurations:

- We use Oracle Weblogic 10.3.3
- Weblogic connects to IBM MQ 7.0 (Problem also appears with 6.0) for JMS
- The above logic is executed by a single thread on a backend server. It would be simple to keep some objects (`QueueConnection`, `QueueSession`, `QueueSender`) in memory as there is no concurrency involved.

### My questions

- Which types of objects can be shared among several messages? (of course we'd include error recovery, restoring those shared objects)
- What are best practices to improve performance?

Comment: I'm very interested in the JMSUtilities.safeClose() methods in your finally block.  Are they part of IBM MQ 7.0?  (Which I'm not using) or something else?  Can't find much with searching.  Implementing my first send to JMS, want to avoid an ugly finally block with lots of null checks.

Comment: @user640118: They're part of a local utility tool-chain. Essentially, they're just performing null-checks and close the objects, no rocket-science.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only thing you need to create again and again is the `msg` itself - if you are sending to the same queue.

So yes, you can remember the Connection, Session and Sender.

Comment: yes, the Queue is always the same. So there is no drawback when keeping a session alive? Of course, we'd have failover logic restoring `Connection`, `Session`, and `Sender` in case they have disconnected....

Comment: What if the connection, or session fails at one point? Do we need create the connection again?

Comment: Are you sure about the Session in multithreads environment ?

Answer (score 16):

Here are some relevant parts of the [jms spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7195-jms-1.1-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/):

section 2.8 Multithreading

```
JMS Object          Supports Concurrent Use
Destination         YES
ConnectionFactory   YES
Connection          YES
Session             NO
MessageProducer     NO
MessageConsumer     NO
```

section 4.4.14 Serial Execution of Client Code

> JMS does not cause concurrent execution of client code unless a client explicitly requests it. One way this is done is to define that a session serializes all asynchronous delivery of messages

So as already mentioned reuse as much as possible. Reuse the ConnectionFactory, Connection and Destinations for all Threads. For each Thread reuse consumers and producers.

If you are reusing a JMS connection beware, that the JMS Provider will multiplex different sessions on that connections. So even if it is safe to reuse connections it might be faster to create a connection for every session you need.

Answer (score 3):

**Define "to share"**.

If you mean to *share among different threads* this is very dangerous. You can **safely share** QueueConnectionFactory object as well as the JMS Connection object. You **must not** share Session, Sender/Consumer or Message objects. Thats the way how TIBCO EMS works I am not sure about IBM platform but I guess this is very same.

If you can be sure your "send" method is *not called by different threads* you can encapulate this into a MySender class with Connection, Session and Sender member variables. But watch out! Do properly close the resources on exit. Thats what Heiko Rupp recommends. Somthing like this:

```
class MySender {
    private QueueConnection connection = null;
    private QueueSession session = null;
    private QueueSender sender = null;

    public MySender(...) { /* initialize conn/sess/sender */ }

    public send(String xmlMsg) { /* sender.send(session.createTextMessage(xmlMsg)) */ }

    public close() { /* close all resources */ }
}
```

Regarding performance. There is no much room for improvement in JMS standard. Keep messages small and optimize server setting. Use durable destinations only when you need it etc. Read documentation for your platform. But on the client side there is not much room. Some platforms offers additional features to JMS that allows some extra performance gain (batch sends etc) but it depends on the platform. I dont know IBM.

Comment: @Izap: Check out my section about the configuration: *The above logic is executed by a single thread on a backend server*. I'm not sure whether you are right about your general assumption that the client side couldn't be optimised. After all, these are resources that are allocated and managed by the Weblogic server in cooperation with MQ...

Comment: To say _You should not share JMS Connection object_ is just wrong, from [the Connection javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Connection.html)... _Connections support concurrent use_

Comment: @Matt, Izap distinguishes **should not** and **must not**, which makes sense in the way that `Sessions` are single-threaded objects, but `Connections` are not. I don't know why I shouldn't but it's not necessarily wrong for TIBCO, is it...?

Comment: @Matt: The JMS the specification does *not* say anything about thread safety. It depends on the implementation. But for Connections you are right. You can share it.

Comment: @Lukas Eder: you can share a Connection across n threads in Tibco without any problem at all. I do this on a system handling 000s of messages a second with latency in the low ms. Performance is not improved by going 1:1 session to connection. Some JMS implementations even exploit this (in an arguably dodgy way but still) to do client side fan out to reduce the total no of messages delivered.

Comment: @Izap, but then the implementation is wrong: *Connections support concurrent use.*

Comment: @lzap: yes it does, see section 2.8 of the spec on multithreading.

Comment: 95% of my answer is still true then

Comment: @lzap: it's still somewhat misleading imo, if you just reference the spec then you can say "these objects are threadsafe, these are not" and then it's not misleading at all

Comment: Digging into TIBCO EMS in particular, I'll say that it appears to me that calling createConnection() every time might be necessary in order to take advantage of load-balanced/fault-tolerant server URLs. Those of the form: `http://server1:port1,http://server2:port2`